# What happens to the Client Id and Client Secret in the connected app for the package subscriber?

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, package-install, second-generation-packaging, client-id

I have created a connected app in my org to perform the REST API call to the Metadata API.

Now if I will make this connected app as part of my 2nd Generation Managed Package, Now my question is -

**Will the client id and client secret available in the connected app get updated automatically with the client id and secret of the package subscriber at the time of installation?**

or

**Will the connected app retains my org's Client Id and Secret?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No connected app can have the same ClientId, therefore, you can expect this to be changed/updated when deploying to org(s). the secret is generated automatically as well upon deployment of the new org.

Comment: Ok, so when the subscriber will install this connected app then the client id and secret will be changed as per the subscriber's client id and secret. right?

Comment: the values will change in each installed org. you can give it a try by spinning up a scratch org and deploying metadata .

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, that's really helpful.